# Basic Client/Server model using Unix signals

Tags: c, stream, signal-handling

I've created a basic client/server model using user defined signals (`SIGUSR1` representing bit 1 and `SIGUSR2` for bit 0).
At a high level the algorithm looks something like:

- The server reveals its PID and starts listening.
- The client takes a string from standard input, encodes it to binary and starts streaming it to the server byte by byte.
- The server receives the signals and decodes them.
- The server prints the received string.

### server.c

```
#include <signal.h>


void handler(int signal)
{
    //handler is called at each signal so my storage variables need to persist their values.
    static int i;
    char c;
    static int sequence[8];

    if (signal == SIGUSR1)
        sequence[i++] = 1;
    else if (signal == SIGUSR2)
        sequence[i++] = 0;
    if (i == 8)
    {
        //we have a byte: decode, write and restart
        c = decoder(sequence);
        write(1, &c, 1);
        i = 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = getpid();
    //put str to fd 1.
    putstr_fd("pid: ", 1);
    //put number as str to fd 1.
    putnbr_fd(pid, 1);
    putstr_fd("\n", 1);
    while (1)
    {
        signal(SIGUSR1, handler);
        signal(SIGUSR2, handler);
        pause();
    }
}
```

### client.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//for the sake of not missing up my signals i used only and only write().
void sender(int *sequence, pid_t pid)
{
    int i = 0;  
    while (i < 8)
    {
        if (sequence[i] == 1)
            if (kill(pid, SIGUSR1) == -1)
            {
                write(1, "Oh the package didn't arrive. you're obligated for a refund.\n", 50);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        else if (sequence[i] == 0)
            if (kill(pid, SIGUSR2) == -1)
            {
                write(1, "Oh the package didn't arrive. you're obligated for a refund.\n", 50);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            };
        i++;
        //Road traffic control for signals.
        usleep(500);
    }
    free(sequence);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int *sequence;
    int i = 0;
    //invalid number of args.
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        write(1, "WTF... I'm not executing that.\n", 31);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }   
    pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    while (argv[2][i])
    {
        sequence = encoder(argv[2][i]);
        sender(sequence, pid);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### encoder.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int  *encoder(char c)
{
    int *sequence = malloc(sizeof(*sequence) * 8);
    if (!sequence)
    {
        ft_putstr_fd("couldn't malloc... Give some space greedy\n", 1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int i = 7;
    int decimal = (int)c;

    while (decimal)
    {
        sequence[i--] = decimal % 2;
        decimal /= 2;
    }
    //ok that's a glue code, i encoded and i filled what's left with zeros from MSB side​ some ascii's are 7 bits some are 6. i didn't want to guess. so i glued.
   ​while (i > -1)
       ​sequence[i--] = 0; 
   ​return sequence;
 ​}
```

### decoder.c

```
#include <math.h>

char decoder(int *sequence)
{
   ​int i = 0;
   ​int n = 7;
   ​int result = 0;  
   ​while (i < 8)
   ​{
       ​result += (sequence[i] * pow(2, n));
       ​i++;
       ​n--;
   ​}
   ​return (char)result;
}
```

The program is built using Make, and it functions as it supposed to. I'm interested in judgments regarding my style (if there's one, probably not...) and error handling and performance or just anything you think should be or shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major flaw in the approach is that there's no guaranteed delivery of signals.  If the server doesn't consume a signal quickly enough, it can miss a subsequent delivery of the same signal.  Since the protocol provides no means of error detection/correction or resynchronisation, that will result in corrupt data.

This situation is most likely to occur on heavily loaded systems, so may easily be missed in testing.

---

Both sides write their error messages to standard output (stream 1) but should use standard error (stream 2).

---

We don't need the `decoder()` function, as we can accumulate bits directly into an `unsigned char` rather than an `int[8]`:

```
void handler(int signal)
{
    static int i = 0;
    static unsigned char c = 0;

    c <<= 1;
    c += signal == SIGUSR1;
    if (++i == 8) {
        write(1, &c, 1);
        i = 0;
        c = 0;
    }
}
```

(`c` needs to be unsigned, so that `<<=` has defined semantics.)

We really should check the return value from that `write()`, and reattempt if it wrote nothing (perhaps because it was interrupted by another signal?)

Strictly speaking, in a signal handler, we should be using `sig_atomic_t`.

---

Similarly, we don't need to `encoder()` int a byte array:

```
void sender(char c, pid_t pid)
{
    for (int i = 0x80;  i;  i >>= 1) {
        if (kill(pid, c & i ? SIGUSR1 : SIGUSR2) == -1) {
            write(2, "Oh the package didn't arrive. you're obligated for a refund.\n", 50);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        // Hope this sleep is long enough for receiver to handle signal!
        usleep(500);
    }
}
```

Even if we did, we could pass in a suitable array `int[8]` rather than allocating storage using `malloc()` and requiring the caller to `free()` it.

---

Instead of using fixed value `8` everywhere, portable code should use `CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: yeah i agree, i thought about using the unused bit in ascii encoding as a parity checker however it will detect if just one bit is altered, so you know...,  the other version of this code will be extended to support unicode and it definitely will use some error detection mechanism, for now i used a simple 500 micro seconds sleep for every signal which somewhat ensures a proper delivery. a proper slow delivery !!

Comment: that's so beautifully compact, it's unnecessarily fancy which makes it even more beautiful, a question of performance, does it perform better than old code?

Comment: I'd expect it to perform measurably better than the code that uses `malloc()`, yes.

Comment: I am squeamish about leaving `i==8` and then calling a function.  Perhaps a paranoid concern about reentrancy into `handler()`? Perhaps `write(1, &c, 1);  i = 0;` --> `i = 0; write(1, &c, 1);`.
`

Comment: Reentrancy in `handler()` will break the output anyway, I think.  There's not much we can do to fix that, given we don't have fully-queued reliable signal delivery.

Comment: `unsigned char c = 0;` is not `static`.  Code looks wrong now.

Comment: That was a slip of the keyboard (please do edit my posts for silly mistakes like that - Rollback is an option if I strongly disagree!)

Comment: @Question, I rejected your proprosed edit: as chux mentioned in a now-deleted comment, we should use unsigned type with `<<`, to avoid Undefined Behaviour.  It's fine to pass that to `write()` and expect it to be treated same as `char`, if you were worried.